# Json method returns Object literal, expected JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm trying to return `JSON`, to map to a model, however I can't figure out why my method is returning an object literal and not `JSON`.

I threw together a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GentleMaN/7u7qebr5/14/) that shows the current format I am receiving data.

### Controller method

```
 public JsonResult GetDeferredAccountDetailsByAccount(int id)
        {
            var details = _deferredAccountDetailsService.GetDeferredAccountDetailsByAccount(id);

            return Json(details, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This returns :

[image]

..And in the browser :

[image]

In the Fiddle I linked, simply wrapping the object literal in `[]` allows Knockout to interpret the object just fine, but without it fails.

Is there something I am doing incorrectly or a reason why I'm not receiving `JSON`? Do I need to return an `ICollection` or something for it to be interpreted as `JSON`?

I looked around but couldn't really find anything.

Comment: You expects an Array, but you are returning a literal object at the controller. And you are biding a collection using knockout, but accounts its a literal. That's why everithing works when you put [] at the JSON,

Comment: Oh, duh. Because of `_map` right?

Comment: Yeah, you should just push every property from the JSON to an Array instead of map, or fix the map function!

Comment: @Fals Thanks! I must have been looking at it too long... If you want to throw it in an answer I'll upvote + accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expects an Array, but you are returning a literal object at the controller. And you are biding a collection using knockout, but accounts It's a literal. That's why everything works when you put [] at the JSON.

You should just push every property from the JSON to an Array instead of `_map`, or fix the `_map` function to bind property to an Array!